# Why does PopupMenuButton dropdown overlaps statusBar?

Tags: flutter, popupmenubutton

When I set initialValue for PopupMenuButton, the dropdown overlaps statusbar. How can I avoid this? Also, How to make PopupMenuButton's dropdown position below appbar?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your Scaffold's body in a SafeArea widget?

Comment: Nope that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Any update on this? I have same problem 

Comment: Adding a PopupMenuButton as an action of the AppBar, I find the location of the popup menu to be non-standard. I would like to see it appear BELOW the AppBar

Answer (score -1):

You can try adidng this:

```
  Widget getMessageText(double parentHeight, double parentWidth) {
    return Padding(
      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(right:parentWidth*0.06),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);

            },
            child: Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: parentHeight*0.02,left: parentWidth*.03),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(
                    "All Posts",
                    style: CommonWidget.getHelveticaBoldTextStyle(
                        textFont, Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7)),
                    textScaleFactor: 1.1,
                  //  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);


            },
            child: Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: parentHeight*0.03,left: parentWidth*.03),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Posts",
                    style: CommonWidget.getHelveticaBoldTextStyle(
                        textFont, Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7)),
                    textScaleFactor: 1.1,
                    //  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){

              Navigator.pop(context);

            },
            child: Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: parentHeight*0.03,left: parentWidth*.03),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Complaints",
                    style: CommonWidget.getHelveticaBoldTextStyle(
                        textFont, Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7)),
                    textScaleFactor: 1.1,
                    //  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );



  }
```